# Vue-cli mode switching

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

How can I use both “dev” and “production” modes when using custom .env files (for configuration of different regions) it just defaults to development env even if running “npm run build — — mode se”

I could of cause have two .env files for each region and hardcore the build mode but hope to avoid it.